# Error in ODBC but not in CLI for Hive?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, odbc, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to query Hive. I also have access to a CLI for entering queries. When I enter the query in CLI, everything runs, but when I enter it in pydobc

```
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

I get this error:

```
Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Cloudera][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '0' error message: 'java.io.IOException: java.io.EOFException'. (35) (SQLFetch)")
```

Sometimes it runs fine without giving this error, and sometimes it fails. I am at a loss as to what is causing this. It only happens when I select a subset of columns, not SELECT *.

Answer (score 0):

The message from ODBC shows the "java.io.IOException: java.io.EOFException" which is an exception thrown in a Java stack. The error is very likely not originated from within the ODBC driver but in the server.

The ODBC driver communicates with Hive through the Thrift server (Hive Server 1 or Hive Server 2) but CLI by-passes the Thrift server. Have you try using beeline to reproduce this issue? Beeline uses the open-source JDBC driver to communicate with Hive through the Thrift server.

If this issue is also reproducible with beeline then the error might be originated from the Thrift server while fetching the results. In that case you may want to check the server logs for more details about the error. If you are using CDH you can check the HiveServer2 log in Cloudera Manager (I am guessing you are likely using Hive Server 2).

Cheers,
Holman

Comment: Hi Holman, beeline is the CLI that we use. It doesn't error out in beeline, only in pyodbc.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, Andrew.

Comment: A couple more things to try: 1. Add UseNativeQuery=1 to your connection string or DSN. 2. Add RowsFetchedPerBlock=50 to your connection or DSN.

Comment: I'll try that next time it comes up. It is hard to debug because it only happens a minority of the time.